# how can i make the background image for <body> adapt?

Tags: html, css

newbie here.
I've set a background image for body but when the window size changes too much the image does not fit. what can i do to eliminate white spaces?
(I apologize if the question is silly, but not knowing what the problem is, I struggle to find a solution.
thanks for the attention!)

[image: this --->]

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: url("img/background.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: No one image can fit all the device aspect ratios out there, let alone cater for any random aspect ratio a user might create for the viewport by resizing the window. I would have expected background-size: cover which you are using to at least cover the body - though of course with either top/bottom or sides cropped as needed to fit things in but it should maintain the image without stretching. Where are you seeing the 'white-space' you mention?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the background-attachment and background-position to fill the background.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: url("img/background.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately background-attachment: fixed is not supported in IOS - you will see a 'zoomed/spludgey' background.